# Attempt at sequence proof $\frac{n+3}{n^2 -3}$ converges to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

> Prove convergence of the following sequence: $$\frac{n+3}{n^2 -3} \rightarrow 0$$

**Proof discussion:**

Notice that since whenever $n>3$,  we have $n^2 -3 >0$, we also know that $n+3 >0$, so $\frac{n+3}{n^2 -3}>0$. This means we can drop the absolute value signs in: 
$$  \left|\frac{n+3}{n^2 -3}-0\right|=\frac{n+3}{n^2 -3} $$
We now notice that for $n>3$ also $n^2 -9>0$ and $n^2 -3 > n^2 -9$ so $\frac{1}{n^2 -3}< \frac{1}{n^2 -9}$ we can thus write:
$$\frac{n+3}{n^2 -3}<\frac{n+3}{n^2 -9}=\frac{(n+3)}{(n+3)(n-3)}=\frac{1}{n-3} $$

To be able to complete this proof we want that $\frac{1}{n-3}<\epsilon$, we write $n-3>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ or $n> \frac{1}{\epsilon} +3$. If we pick $n_0 =\lceil\frac{1}{\epsilon} +3\rceil$, it will also be automatically larger than $3$. We can now write our proof:

**Proof:**
For all $\epsilon>0$, we let $n_0=\lceil{\frac{1}{\epsilon}+3 }\rceil$ then for all $n>n_0$, we know that:

$$|a_n-0|=\left|\frac{n+3}{n^2-3} \right|<\frac{n+3}{n^2-9}=\frac{1}{n-3}< \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\epsilon}+3-3}=\epsilon$$
And hence our sequence converges to $0$ $\square$.

Is my proof okay?

Comment: I think you should make explicit that since $\epsilon>0$, then $n_0\geq 4$, so the denominator in $\left\lvert\frac{n+3}{n^2-3}\right\rvert$ is positive, so you can remove the absolute value sign. Otherwise, I think the proof is perfect.

Comment: Yes, perfect! Just another small mistake: twice you wrote $\epsilon$ instead of $1/\epsilon$. I guess it was just a type since you continued correctly.

Comment: I do make the case that the denominator is positive,  It's in the first line.

Comment: Maybe I should say it explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, the proof is correct.

Also, "we write $n-3>\color{blue}{\frac1{\epsilon}}$"

Comment: Why is this an inequality and not an equality? we can just cancel the $n+3$ right?

Comment: oops, you are right. I made a mistake.

Comment: Thank you. I did do a typo :) you were right about  that

Comment: huzzah! I've done it :D

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, decompose

$$\frac{n+3}{n^2-3}=\frac1{n-\sqrt3}+(3-\sqrt3)\frac1{n^2-3}$$

and the two terms are of the form $\dfrac1\infty$.

Comment: That could work later on in the course, right now I am not yet allowed to use this.

Comment: I realised this is okay since sequences map to $\mathbb{R}$, so you can write it in this manner.

Comment: @WesleyGroupshaveFeelingsToo: isn't $\epsilon$ in $\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: Yes, of course :)